# Что значит "+" и "!" в терминале перед командой?

Tags: linux, bash, консоль

```
+/usr/bin/rm -f foo 
!/usr/bin/rm -f bar
```

Comment: Какую-то ересь. Может это у вас prompt так выглядит, хотя обычно это `$` или `#`.

Comment: Откуда вы это взяли?

Comment: Если это [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) (изменения в файле), то + означает добавленную строку, ! - измененную строку

Comment: Ну справедливости ради, восклицательный знак в терминале выполнит предыдущую запущенную команду, но не в скриптах, т.е. до этого я вызывал `ls -l` после этого выполняю `!ls`  но будет вызвана команда `ls -l`. + это похоже на дебаг версию `-x` bash

Answer (score 6):

Восклицательный знак в начале команды подставляет аргументы программы вызываемые при запуске ранее (Работает только в терминале):

```
cat 1234.txt
# data in 1234.txt
!cat 123.txt
# > cat 1234.txt 123.txt
# data in 1234.txt
# data in 123.txt
!cat
# > cat 1234.txt 123.txt
# data in 1234.txt
# data in 123.txt
```

Стоит отметить, что аргументы подставляются только от той же программы, например:

```
ls -l one.txt
cat 1234.txt
# data in 1234.txt
!ls two.txt
# > ls -l one.txt two.txt
```

Знак + перед командой больше напоминает вывод c дебаг режима `set -x`

```
#Команда уже была передана интерпретатору и он вернул строку в дебаг режиме
+/usr/bin/rm -f foo
#При запуске команды 
!/usr/bin/rm -f bar 
#будет преобразована в 
/usr/bin/rm -f foo -f bar
```

Comment: Не нашел ничего про '+' в [документации](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), вероятно это не bash.

Comment: @Ivan в консоли выполнить `bash -x` и смотреть на появление плюсов в выводе: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8RFS.png

Comment: Эм, ! - про ввод, а + про вывод? Вот это поворот)